# Python Pandas: reindex property deletes all previously existing values

Tags: python, pandas

In the following pandas dataframe (`df`) I would like to set the index equal to the values of column "Order" and then reindex such that, in between the index values to have also the following index values (`order_adj`), with nans accompanying them in the columns of the dataframe:

`order_adj = [30, 182]`

```
       ID          Date            Order    Values
16672  22000118    2019-11-06          9    0.320934 
16673  22000118    2019-11-06         44    0.213926  
16674  22000118    2019-11-06         72    0.178836  
16675  22000118    2019-11-06        135    0.182151  
16676  22000118    2019-11-06        226    0.162838
```

I set the index of the dataframe using the following command:
`df.index = df.Order.values`

```
       ID          Date            Order    Values
9      22000118    2019-11-06          9    0.320934 
44     22000118    2019-11-06         44    0.213926  
72     22000118    2019-11-06         72    0.178836  
135    22000118    2019-11-06        135    0.182151  
226    22000118    2019-11-06        226    0.162838
```

But when I am using `df = df.reindex(index = order_adj)` instead of receiving:

```
       ID          Date            Order    Values
9      22000118    2019-11-06          9    0.320934 
30     nan         nan               nan    nan
44     22000118    2019-11-06         44    0.213926  
72     22000118    2019-11-06         72    0.178836  
135    22000118    2019-11-06        135    0.182151
182    nan         nan               nan    nan  
226    22000118    2019-11-06        226    0.162838
```

I receive

```
       ID          Date            Order    Values
30     nan         naT               nan    nan
182    nan         naT               nan    nan
```

What exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df=df.reindex([*df.index,*order_adj]).sort_index()
```

OR

```
df=df.reindex(df.index.tolist()+order_adj).sort_index()
```

output of `df`:

```
        ID          Date        Order   Values
9       22000118.0  2019-11-06  9.0     0.320934
30      NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN
44      22000118.0  2019-11-06  44.0    0.213926
72      22000118.0  2019-11-06  72.0    0.178836
135     22000118.0  2019-11-06  135.0   0.182151
182     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN
226     22000118.0  2019-11-06  226.0   0.162838
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Index.union()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) to combine the index with `order_adj` in correct sequence.  Then [`.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), as follows:

```
idx = df.index.union(order_adj)
df = df.reindex(idx)
```

or do it in one step, as follows:

```
df = df.reindex(df.index.union(order_adj))
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

             ID        Date  Order    Values
9    22000118.0  2019-11-06    9.0  0.320934
30          NaN         NaN    NaN       NaN
44   22000118.0  2019-11-06   44.0  0.213926
72   22000118.0  2019-11-06   72.0  0.178836
135  22000118.0  2019-11-06  135.0  0.182151
182         NaN         NaN    NaN       NaN
226  22000118.0  2019-11-06  226.0  0.162838
```